# How to get user by Token in django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = ExtUserSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        field = ('title','description','rating','author')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

and

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def post_list(request, format=None):
if request.method == 'GET':
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

How to modify Serializer and view to fill field author automatically